# Node.JS V8 heap growing quickly even though usage remains the same

Tags: node.js, v8

I'm running a Node.JS web application that works fine for a few hours and then at some random point in time, the V8 heap suddenly starts growing very quickly without a reason and about 40 minutes later, this growth usually stops and the process continues running normally.

I'm monitoring this with nodetime:

[image]

[image]

What could be the cause of this? Is it a memory leak in my program or perhaps a bug in V8?

Comment: I see the same. I've been graphing the output of process.memoryUsage() for an app I made and this is what it looks like: http://i.imgur.com/TxvMSwu.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of knowing what the issue by what you provided, but there's a 99.99% chance the problem is inside / fixable in your code.

The best tools I've found for debugging memory issues with Node.js is https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-heapdump, you can set it up to dump a certain intervals, or by default it listens to USR2 signal, so you can send `kill -s USR2` to the pid of your process and get the snapshot.

Then you can use Chrome Inspector to load the heap into it's profiling tool and start inspecting.

I've generally found the issues to be around holding on to external requests too long.

Comment: Damn, it seems my current server doesn't have enough memory to create a full snapshot, but I'll mark this as the answer because the data from a test snapshot does look very useful.

Comment: I found that the heapdump is only 300 MB, even though the memory usage is 1.4 GB, so I'm going to have to try something else.

Comment: The size of the dumps don't equal the size of the memory usage. I'd do a dump that was 28MB files size but the memory usage was over 200MB, what you are looking for are objects that have grown too large or have too many still instantiated.

Comment: Yes, but process.memoryUsage() shows the same difference between total heap size and usage.